# Using a different Python IDE/debugger for ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I effectively debug arcpy Python scripts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-effectively-debug-arcpy-python-scripts)

I prefer to use [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) over IDLE as my IDE/debugger for writing GP scripts in Python.  In ArcGIS, however, when I right-click on a geoprocessing "Tool" that references a Python script, it always opens in IDLE.

What is the best way to change the default tool that ArcGIS is calling?

**Edit:** I am currently running 9.3, but am transitioning to 10 soon, so suggestions for both versions is appreciated if they are different.

Comment: also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-effectively-debug-arcpy-python-scripts