# How is Python IDE aware of ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy, installation, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 4 for some Python scripting.

When I type:

```
import arcpy
```

I can immediately start using items within the arcpy namespace, like the environment & workspace objects.

How does the Python IDE, in this case PyCharm, know about ArcPy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Help page entitled [Importing ArcPy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z00000008000000) that explains this - I encourage you to visit that page which has more detail than I am quoting:

> When using an import statement, Python looks for a module matching
>   that name in the following locations (and in the following order):
>
> 1. Paths specified in the PYTHONPATH system environment variable
> 2. A set of standard Python folders (the current folder, c:\python2x\lib, c:\python2x\Lib\site-packages, and so on)
> 3. Paths specified inside any .pth file found in 1 and 2

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/128356) to [How to setup PyCharm to reference ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/how-to-setup-pycharm-to-reference-arcpy) may also be helpful.