# Python IDE complete code autocompletion

Tags: python

I am seeing that code completion in both PyScripter and PyCharm is not complete, compared to the code completion you get in the interpreter window. In PyScripter, if you add arcpy to the code completion IDE options, you will get all the options, but having this added, causes errors in the program, for some reason. Thats why I am testing with PyCharm. In PyCharm the issue is the same, in the editor window I am unable to see all the options I see in the interpreter window while typing. Anyone know why or how to fix?

Edit:

Interpreter config
[image: Interpreter config]

Example

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suppose you have configured the python interpreter (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/how-to-setup-pycharm-to-reference-arcpy). Did you have an example of missing option?

Comment: Yes It configured all the folders when selection the appropiate python.exe. I have edited the post with the picture and an example. THanks